# How to Abort/Prevent/Stop af:inputFile Uploading File using Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw many solution with uploading file provided here but it seems doesn't work for my case. Here is the scenario that I try to achieve:

- I would like to check the size of file after user choose the file that they want to upload
- In JS it will checks is it greater than (for example) 100 Bytes

  - If true, I want to prevent it from uploading the file, else it's just fine to upload the file

The file size validation is fine, the issue is, somehow I couldn't prevent af:inputFile from uploading the file after it exits the javascript validation.

Please kindly give me advice on how to prevent it to upload from javascript/jQuery.

Here is my code:

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.UploadFile input').on("change", function (e) {
      if (this.files[0] != null) {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size;

        if (fileSize > 100) {
          alert("File too large!");
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
        else {
          alert("File ok");
        }
      }
    });
    });
```

The af:inputFile

```
<af:inputFile label="Upload" id="if1" autoSubmit="true"
                    styleClass="UploadFile" immediate="true"
                    valueChangeListener="#{fileBean.attachFile}">
</af:inputFile>
```

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to reset the `input type=file` if the condition doesn't match as below:

```
$('.UploadFile input').on("change", function (e) {
    if (this.files[0] != null) {
        var fileSize = this.files[0].size;
        if (fileSize > 100) {
            alert("File too large!");
            var control=$("#"+$(this).attr('id'));//get the id
            control.replaceWith(control = control.clone().val(''));//replace with clone
            return;
        }
        else {
            alert("File ok");
        }
    }
});
```

> Also do note that `this.files[0].size` returns file size in
>   **`bytes`**. So according to your validation, you will not allow to upload file whose size is more that `100 bytes`

Comment: Hi @Guruprasad, I tried this on my local machine and I got a stopper "Object doesn't support property or method 'clone'" in browser debugger

Comment: Sorry.. My bad.. Just wrap `"#"+$(this).attr('id')` inside `$()` like `var control=$("#"+$(this).attr('id'));` .. I've updated my answer..

Comment: Thankyou! Somehow it seems close to fix my issue, will do little bit edit and hope it works @Guruprasad

Comment: Sure.. Try your best.. Happy Coding.. :)